# iptables hashlimit

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

**Настраиваю iptables, и у меня возник вопрос, мне нужно ограничить количество tcp пакетов отправленных на определенный порт.**

Как это в теории у меня будет выглядить:

```
# если больше 5 конектов с одного ип к данному порту, 6\7\8\9 итд конект дропаем
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 2107 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 5 -j DROP

# если с одного ип отправляется больше 10 пакетов в секунду, то дропаем этот конект
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 2107 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-above 10/s -j DROP
```

Будет ли это работать?

Comment: А проверить не вариант?

Comment: ещё тип хэша настроить не помешает

Comment: обязательно укажи тип tcp `syn`

Comment: @eri если не сложно, можешь показать пример как должна выглядеть строка